# How to turn android to sleep mode

Tags: android

I build a simple application to test the sleep option of the android mobile

I put this code inside the button:

```
Intent lockscreen=new Intent();
lockscreen.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
startActivity(lockscreen);
```

with no change ,
also I put the permission...I want when I press this button my phone would locked (not locked by password) (normal lock)
Any Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is a broadcast `Intent`, not one used with `startActivity()`.

Second, as the documentation for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` states, "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system".

> I want when I press this button my phone would locked (not locked by password) (normal lock)

You are welcome to use the [device admin APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) and use `lockNow()` on `DevicePolicyManager`, which should achieve this effect.

Comment: @AnasZOKO: If you read the documentation that I linked to, it says that you need `BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN`.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />   thanks

Comment: Now I try :DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
 mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE)
 
mDPM.lockNow();
when I reach to mDPM.lock()  my application will crash (by debug )
What Is missed